# Как интегрировать парсер в WordPress сайт?

Tags: php, wordpress, веб-программирование, парсер, curl

Я сделал парсер PHP, который копирует данные с других сайтов.
Как интегрировать парсер на сайте WordPress.
Я имею ввиду, что все скопированные данные появятся в моих записях WordPress.

Comment: Создай плагин с кодом парсера.

Comment: Лучше парсер положить в корень сайта, откуда его можно будет запускать cron'ом, например. А в самом парсере дописать код, который будет делать запросы в БД для сохранения записей